# How can I install gstreamer 1.0 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to install GStreamer 1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, the default GStreamer that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 is `gst` `0.10`. I could see that I could download the GStreamer 1.0 source from [gstreamer.freedesktop.org](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src), build it and install it. But this installs only the `gst` plugins only, it does not install the actual required libraries like:

- mpeg2dec,
- h264,
- and other dependent libraries.

These libraries are required by the gst plugins.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed you may need to install that, and any other libraries you require from the repositories.

If you want to install gstreamer 1.0, you need to use the backports for Precise from [the gstreamer developers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gstreamer-developers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise), which is the best source at the minute and the most 'official' developer ppa available.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

This will install all the base packages and plugins that you require, and is fine to install, even though you also have the earlier version installed as well, although applications will not use gstreamer1.0 unless they have been built with support for it.

---

For more information regarding ppas, please see these discussions:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: it also worked in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The "gstreamer-developers" PPA is unavailable as of April 2016, and I could not get any explanation from any involved parties. As of that date - about a year before the end of official LTS support for precise, there is no way (that I could find) to install gstreamer-1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6):

Installing the below package should do the magic

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: This doesn't work on 12.04 because only 0.10 is available on 12.04. It will bring all the gstreamer-0.10 stuff but not 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 16.04, this worked for me, it might on Ubuntu 12.04 as well:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: 1.0 is not available on 12.04. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

[Install GStreamer on Ubuntu or Debian](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html)

```
apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools
```

pkgconfig path in my pc:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gstreamer-1.0.pc
```

Building Application using Gstreamer

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0
```

Comment: The only accurate answer in the thread

Answer (score 0):

I found that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490082/ubuntu-16-install-gstreamer-but-gstreamer-plugins-base-1-0-pc-file-is-not-found)... and I am adding it. 
I was trying to install Wine 64bit and I could not figure out how to install gstreamer-1.0 base plugins 64-bit development files

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev**
```