# Is there any light user interface or gtk package for Gstreamer 1.0?

Tags: gui, gtk, gstreamer

I have just installed package gstreamer 1.0, and I use as executable the file located in
 ~/usr/bin/gst-play-1.0 .

All is fine, I can play local files, and also I can use 'gst-play-1.0' in TV-MAXE to watch live video streams. I was wondering if there is some GUI or a gtk package in a repository out there to make gstreamer work with the keyboard so I be able to see videos in fullscreen, and maybe pause the video or even change brightness and so on. Fulscreen feature would be nice to have for Gstreamer.

I have read lots of tutorials on the Internet but they are all for developers, and advanced Linux users, I can't understand nothing from those scripts and suggestions.

For the moment I can [watch videos and live streams](http://i60.tinypic.com/fw3bbl.png) adjusting the screen size manually, it is not that bad, image and sound are great, but maybe someone knows a package that works for Gstreamer, and includes a very useful interface for the average user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what happened since I first posted my question, but I recently tested again  **gstreamer 1.0** and it goes fullscreen now (using the  **menu button** in the upper-left section of player's window to enter fullscreen), I can pause video with the **space** key and I suppose there are also other useful commands available that I haven't tried yet.

I followed a guide from [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279509/how-can-i-install-gstreamer-1-0-in-ubuntu-12-04), installed gstreamer 1.0 with all its dependencies, and it worked just fine for streaming videos at least. I use it to watch tv-maxe channels, and I have no complaints so far. Basically, all I had to do was to run this commands in a terminal window:

```
         sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
         sudo apt-get update
         sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

I tested this on Xubuntu 12.04.5 so I can't promise it works for Ubuntu 14.04 or Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the default package in Ubuntu answering your question is [Totem](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/totem/):

```
   Totem - GNOME desktop movie player based on GStreamer
```

Comment: Yes, Totem is ok, but it is way too heavy, and it uses a lot of cpu. On my machine, Totem goes all way up to 90% cpu usage for live streams. What I liked about Gstreamer 1.0 was its simplicity, and its useful codec packages (it is also CPU friendly - around 30-40% cpu usage for HD live streams), and I really hope there is some other user interface for Gstreamer that can match its native features. Totem may be a first choice for a new computer but it is definitely not for me (Dell Optiplex machine, 2000 MHz P4 cpu, 1024 ram, 128 Mib Nvidia fx5200 video card).